# C How to free a dynamic string inside multidimensional dyamic struct?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
struct Link
{
    frame_t *frame;
    struct Link *next;
} typedef link_t;
```

Inside I allocate memory for frame_t
I tried recursively freeing it but the program crashed when I ran it.

```
struct Frame
{
    char            *name;
    unsigned int    duration;
    char            *path;
} typedef frame_t;
```

And inside of that I allocate memory for name and path.

```
void freeFrames(link_t** head)
{
    if (*head != NULL)
    {
        if ((*head)->next != NULL)
        {
            free((*head)->frame->name);
            free((*head)->frame->path);
            free((*head)->frame);
            freeFrames(&((*head)->next));
        }

        free(*head);
    }
}
```

How can I free memory for this?

Comment: You need to also check whether `(*head)->frame` is not NULL.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It is impossible to tell why it crashed without seeing the entire program, but your freeFrames function is wrong, it will not free the frame of the last element of the list thanks to the redundant `if ((*head)->next != NULL)` check.

Comment: Getting rid of pointer-to-pointers and recursion would be the first step.

Comment: Don't you think before doing `free(*head);` you would also require some condition?

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you initialised the pointers correctly? If you did not assign a concrete value to them, you must initialise them to NULL.
2. You cannot free a null pointer, so you should check: `if(name) free(name);`
3. You cannot free string literals! So if you do `name = "hello"`, your program is guaranteed to fail if trying to do so.

Additionally, you have a memory leak (stole that one from n.m.'s comment...):

```
if ((*head)->next != NULL)
{
    free((*head)->frame->name);
    free((*head)->frame->path);
    free((*head)->frame);
    // ^ you will only free, if there is a successor node!
    //   so you won't free them on the last node!

    freeFrames(&((*head)->next));
}
```

It should be (not having added the NULL checks so far!):

```
if(*head)
{
    free((*head)->frame->name);
    free((*head)->frame->path);
    free((*head)->frame);
    if ((*head)->next != NULL)
    {
        freeFrames(&((*head)->next));
    }
    free(*head);
}
```

Additionally: You do not assign anything to your head (`*head = NULL;`), so why do you have a double pointer?

```
void freeFrames(link_t* head);
```

would suffice...

And there is no need for recursion, you simply can advance the pointer as long as there is any:

```
void freeFrames(link_t* head)
{
    while(head)
    {
        // free members, don't forget the NULL checks
        link_t* tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```